# What happened to android:layout_gravity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I was wondering what happened to android:layout_gravity. My code looks like this :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/test_button"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="test"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
```

but the center does absolutely nothing on the button and eclipse doesn't even have it on their drop down menu. Is their another way to do it now?

Comment: Try cleaning your project. `Project -> Clean`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/test_button"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="test"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout?
```

[android:layout_gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_gravity) is in [LinearLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_gravity)

So, It works in LinearLayout.

Or change like below (regardless of parent)

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/test_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="test"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
```

Comment: Oh i forgot about the linearlayout Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

What layout are you using? If your button is in a RelativeLayout, that may be your issue. You can work with LinearLayout, and use layout_gravity. Or in RelativeLayout, you can align the views as you see fit.